How to capture cell value on Excel? Without using VBA
1
I'd like to make if TODAY()=A2 then on C2 cell value must only per day 1 time update from B2 and put value on cell C2 and after that must not to be changed C2 while if B2 even will change.
]2
I tryed this formula on excel but still something is missing
=IF(TODAY()=A2; B2; C2)

So, are you saying you want C2 to capture the first (and only the first) value that gets typed into B2?  Excel can't do that.  You may need to have the user do that by hand.  What happens if the data entry person makes a typo?

I'm sure it's possibe just I'm new by using  excel formulas that is my issue. What do you mean by typo?

Say the data entry person typed 10000 when they meant 1000.  C2 now captured the wrong value.  If they fix it to 1000, C2 will be wrong.  I don't think you have thought through all the potential edge conditions.

I guess you don't understand. Let me explain.
IF current date equals to A2 date then do next copy B2 cell value to C2 only one time. Else if B2 value is changed manually second or third or.... C2 value must stay before.
BECAUSE PER DAY ONLY 1 TIME COPY CELL OF B2 TO C2.

No, I get it.  That can't be done with Excel formulas.  You can't force a cell to "commit suicide" by replacing its own value with something else, and that's what you're asking.  You're asking for a formula that converts itself to a number.  VBA can do that, but not Excel formulas.
